# Como bajar el sdk de android 4.2 a android 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una aplicación casi terminada pero cuando la cree le puse el minSdk con valor 14, lo que necesito ponerla como mínimo Android 2.3 Saludos.

Comment: Se puede entra en el fichero gradle de tu app y en miSdkVersion lo puedes modificar, tienes tambien tener en cuenta que depende de que Api uses no es soportada con versiones tan "obsoletas"

Comment: @Webserveis tienes razón, es un problema soportar estas versiones, yo aún uso en aplicaciones minSDK 8 (Froyo) y se tienen que validar muchas cosas, todo un gran problema ...

Answer (score 2):

Te diriges a build.gradle en `defaultConfig` y colocas el `minSdkVersion` que es 10:

Ejemplo:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mx.xxx.aplicacion"
        minSdkVersion 10
        ...
    }
```

**Después, click en el botón de Sync**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Existen dos formas, la primera es directamente en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` donde defines la propiedad:

**[android:minSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)**

en la cual defines la minima API en la cual tu aplicación será soportada. La versión de la API para [**Android 2.3 es 9**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.html), por lo tanto este sería el valor:

**android:minSdkVersion = 9**

La segunda opción es definir la versión de SDK dentro de tu archivo [**build.gradle**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) con la propiedad **minSdkVersion** :

```
android {
    ...
    ...    
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 9
        ...
        ...
    }
```

En la [**documentación**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) puedes ver las constantes para definir la constante de API para el OS Android 2.3 y los demás.

Answer (score 2):

A la respuesta de @ElenaSys habría que agregar una serie de puntos a tener en cuenta al momento de hacer el cambio, ya que en Android 2.3 no existían muchas APIs que hoy se usan como base.

La recomendación es usar la [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) (en especial [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat)) para poder aprovechar varias de las mejoras que se han ido introduciendo en versiones posteriores de Android.

Creo que las mas comunes son:

- Fragments
- ActionBar
- NotificationCompat
- Loaders

En vez de

```
class ActivityMain extends Activity {
...
}
```

Deberías usar

```
class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {
...
}
```

[AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

En caso que tengas definido algún theme, en vez de

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
...
</style>
```

Deberías empezar a usar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
...
</style>
```

Puse como ejemplo Theme.AppCompat.Light, pero hay otras alternativas

Esto es solo una base para que te des una idea. Te dejo dos links (en ingles) para que puedas sacar mas información.

- [Supporting Different Platform Versions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html?hl=es)
- [Maintaining Compatibility](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)